# how to subtract DB timestamp from current timestamp in Oracle

Tags: timestamp, subtraction

I have a timestamp field in oracle table. I want to deduct that timestamp field from current timestamp. How can I do that?

```
Select date_time from test where id = 123;
```

returns

`14-02-12 11:00:00 -03:30` as a result. (Note: date_time type is timestamp).

I want to subtract date_time field from current timestamp. Any help please.

Comment: timezone. We can trim that. We don't need to use that.

Comment: after the subtraction, you want values in days, months, years ?

Comment: Mostly I need hour, minutes, and seconds as well.